# С# - Вне границ массива

Tags: c#

Задание: Ввести двумерный целочисленный рваный массив и убрать из него положительные строки. Проблема: в определенном моменте индекс выскакивает за пределы массива. Не могу понять как исправить.

```
    class Program
{

    static int[][] MatrixInput(int n)
    {
        int m;
        int[][] arr = new int[n][];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Количество элементов в {0} строке:  ", i + 1);
            m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            arr[i] = new int[m];
        }
        Console.Write("Введите элементы: \n");

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)

            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].Length; ++j)
            {
                Console.Write("a[{0},{1}]= ", i, j);
                arr[i][j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        return arr;

    }
    static void MatrixOutput(int[][] arr, int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)

            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].Length; ++j) // Ошибка здесь

                Console.Write("{0,5} ", arr[i][j]);
    }
    static bool DeleteRow(int[] x)
    {
        foreach (int value in x)
        {
            if (value >= 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter count of arrays");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the elements of matrix: ");
        int[][] array = MatrixInput(n);

        int[] x = new int[n];
        int newSize = 0;
        foreach (int[] row in array)
        {
            if (DeleteRow(row))
            {
                newSize++;
            }
        }

        int[][] output = new int[newSize][];

        int rowCounter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (DeleteRow(array[i]))
            {
                output[rowCounter] = array[i];
                rowCounter++;
            }
        }

            Console.WriteLine("Matrix after removing: ");

            MatrixOutput(output, n);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: А отладчиком смотрели где и какой индекс за границы выходит?

Comment: Вы предлагаете нам гадать, в каком именно месте в вашем коде возникает проблема?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов , Комментарием указано "Ошибка здесь"

Comment: @Bigniggaboss я не спрашиваю где ошибка. Я спрашиваю ВЫ смотрели отладчиком?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, Да, смотрел отладчиком. Индекс выходит за границу именно в том месте, где стоит комментарий

Comment: @Bigniggaboss осваивайте отладчик и далее, он как раз и служит для поиска ошибок в программах.

Comment: У вас какой-то странный метод `DeleteRow(int[] x)`, на первом же положительном элементе происходит выход из метода, остальные оставшиеся элементы не проверяются совсем. И я так понимаю, что не худо было бы складывать элементы проверяемой строки, чтоб ответить на вопрос положительна ли строка или нет? Да, и вы еще не проходили ООП? Почему пишете в процедурном стиле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!DeleteRow(row))
{
   newSize++;
}


MatrixOutput(output, output.Length);
```